# combining graphql query with a subscription

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am using graphql subscriptions to get a stream of live messages. The question I have is how to combine this with a query as there are messages from the past.

My example is I have a `MessagesQuery` component that fetches all previous messages, but to display newer messages I am using a `MessageSubscription` component.

Can anyone explain the best approach for this? I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/798) but unfortunately no feedback has been. given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue describes the typical approach -- use the `Query` component or `useQuery` hook and call `subscribeToMore` to tack on a subscription. That user's problem seemed to be that the subscription unsubscribes on unmount but that is appropriate and expected behavior.

Example usage:

```
const { subscribeToMore, ...result } = useQuery(MESSAGES_QUERY, otherOptions)
subscribeToMore({
  document: MESSAGES_SUBSCRIPTION,
  updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
    // merge the subscription data into the query result
  },
})
```

See [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions/#subscribetomore) for additional details.

Comment: Unless you track it on the server side, this approach can easily miss events or you can even have duplicates if there's no way to deduplicate. The query and subscription are not aligned. In other words, the subscription does not continue "after" the query. It's a best-effort approach.

Has anyone found a good solution to work around that problem?

Comment: @fischerman Assuming you have cursor-based pagination, you can effectively ignore the payload of the subscription and just use the subscription event as a trigger to fetch any messages after the last one stored on the client. Then combine the results like you do with any other paginated list (i.e. `fetchMore`).